# Subtracting a sub set from a set in alloy

Tags: set, subset, alloy

I am playing around with alloy and I am using a pretty simple example. What I am trying to do is return the set of a specifics person's aunts. I am trying to accomplish with the following code, but it is not working as I don't think I can subtract a subset from a set? I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the following code for the Man and Person signifier:

```
abstract sig Person {
    father: lone Man,
    mother: lone Woman,
    spouse: lone Person,
}

sig Man extends Person { }
```

Here is the following code for the function:

```
fun aunt: Person->Person{
    (parent.sibling)-Man
}
```

So what I want this function to return is simply the set of ONLY my aunts, where parent.sibling returns the set of both aunts and uncles.I am not sure where I am going wrong, and thank you for all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: Could you edit your question so as to show how you defined a sibling ? Also, aunt is a person, so why returning a relation from Person to Person ?

Comment: This might be easier to define as part of the `Person` signature rather than a separate function.